# Ruby on Rails setting two users as admin w/ ldap authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ldap, admin

New to Ruby on Rails and I have a show page which has information that has been filled out from the new page including radio buttons which allow or deny the request form. I'd like every person that's able to login using the ldap authentication that's set up already to be able to view the show page information. But I need only two users, which will be admins, to be able to see the radio buttons to allow or deny the request form. I've used many different tutorials and the similar question i've seen online doesn't really help me out. The is_admin? method in the articles_controllers is not a real method and would like help with that. The users that login with their ldap credentials username is in the form of "john_smith". I apologize in advance for my poor coding skills. If there is any additional information needed I can supply that fairly quickly.

This is the code for the show page. app\views\articles\show.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
p.inq
{
    width:400px; 
    word-wrap:break-word;;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="logo"></div>
<center>
<h1> Submitted Request </h1>
<table><tr><p>

<td><strong>Approval Status:</strong></td>
 <td>  &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp       </td>  
 <td><%= @article.approve %></td></p></tr>
  <p><tr><td><strong>Name:</strong></td>
    <td>  &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp       </td>
    <td><%= @article.name %></td>
  </p></tr>
  <tr><p>
    <td><strong>Email:</strong></td>
    <td>       </td>
    <td><%= @article.email %></td>
  </p></tr>
  <tr> <p>
    <td><strong>Phone Number:</strong></td>
    <td>       </td>
    <td><%= @article.phone_number %></td>
  </p></tr>
    <tr><p>  
    <td><strong>Department Name</strong></td>
  <td>      </td>
  <td><%= @article.dept_name %></td>
  </p></tr>

      <tr><p>  
    <td><strong>Desc. of Business Need:</strong></td>
      <td>      </td>
  <td><%= @article.dob %></td>
  </p></tr>

  <tr><p>  
    <td><strong>Desc. of Changes to Firewall:</strong></td>
  <td>      </td>
  <td><%= @article.doc %></td>
  </p></tr>
    <tr><p>  

    <tr><p>  
    <td><strong>Additional Information(NAT's, VIPS's, Servers, etc.:</strong></td>
  <td>      </td>
  <td><%= @article.info %></td>
  </p></tr>

    <tr><p>
    <td><strong>Inquiry:</strong></td>
    <td>     </td>
    <td><p class="inq"><%= @article.inquiry %></p></td>
  </p></tr></table>
  <%= :username %>
  <% if is_admin? %>

  <%= form_for :article, :method => :patch, url: article_path(@article) do |f| %>
  <%= f.radio_button :approve, 'Approved' %> 
    <%= f.label :approve, 'Approve Request', :value => 'Approved' %> &nbsp &nbsp
    <%= f.radio_button :approve, 'Denied' %>
    <%= f.label :approve, 'Deny Request', :value => 'Denied' %>&nbsp &nbsp
     <%= f.radio_button :approve, 'Unapproved' %>
    <%= f.label :approve, 'Keep Request Unapproved', :value => 'Unapproved' %><br><br>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %><br>
 <% end %><% end %>

  <%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
  </center></body>
```

app\models\user.rb

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
    # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
           :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable

   def self.generate_random_password
        Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(Time.now.to_s)
    end 

    def create
        User.create(user_params)
    end  
    private 
    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:firstname, :lastname, :displayname, :username, :email,       :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me)
    end
  end
```

app\controllers\articles_controllers.rb

```
  class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def show  
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

  def create 
     @article = Article.new(article_params)

    respond_to do |format|
     if  @article.save
            FormMailer.confirmation_email(@article).deliver
            AdminMailer.confirmation_email(@article).deliver
            format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: 'successful' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @article }
        #redirect_to @article
      else 
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        #render 'new'
    end
   end
  end 

  helper_method :is_admin?
  def is_admin?
      notsure == 'john_smith'
     end

  def index  
    @articles = Article.all 
  end

  def edit 
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])

    if @article.update(art_param)
        redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  private 
  def article_params    
        params.require(:article).permit(:name, :email, :phone_number, :dept_name, :doc,             :inquiry, :dob, :info, :time)
  end

  def art_param
    params.require(:article).permit(:approve)
  end

  end
```

app\views\devise\sessions\new.html.erb

```
  <center><h2>Request Form - Sign In</h2>
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
      Welcome <%= current_user.email %> (<%= link_to "logout", destroy_user_session_path,              :method => :delete %>)
  <% else %>
      You are currently not logged in,  <%= link_to "Log In Here",       user_omniauth_authorize_path(:ldap) %>
  <% end %>

  <!-- <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <div><%= f.label :username %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :username, autofocus: true %></div>

    <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

    <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
      <div><%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %></div>
    <% end -%>

    <div><%= f.submit "Sign in" %></div>
  <% end %> 

  <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>-->
  </center>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you want your is_admin? method to trigger before the user is able to activate any of the actions in the controller. This means, it should be a before_filter rather than a helper method. Now, you can fill in your is_admin? method so it does what you want it to do if the user is an admin. Here's an example of how it might work for you (below, only the admin can user the new and create methods). You can modify it however you want so if the user tries to activate the methods, they are redirected elsewhere or are given an alert.

```
before_filter :is_admin? , only: [:new, :create]

def is_admin?
 return current_user
end
```